# Обрезка фона, чтобы увидеть себя в контексте наложения

Tags: javascript, css, вёрстка, svg, svg-animation

[**Примечание**. Ищете кроссбраузерное решение, которое не мигает на мгновение background'ом между каждой волной слизи (`goo`), как видно из ответа `@ccprog` В идеале решение не должно включать ожидание окончания первой волны, чтобы начать отображение второй волны, нужно чтобы обе волны могли работать одновременно. Я готов отказаться от динамически рандомизированной группы, чтобы найти идеальное решение. ]

Кто-нибудь знает, как я могу заставить вторую волну оранжевой слизи (`.goo-two`) «прорезать» первую волну коричневой слизи (`.goo-one`) и контейнер Skyblue (`.goo-container`), чтобы показать или обнажить красный элемент тела (body) или, если на то пошло, любой другой элемент ниже него в контексте стека?

Возможно ли это сделать?

Примечательно, что причина, по которой я дал контейнеру `.goo-container` сплошной фон, заключается в том, что я использовал его, чтобы прикрыть процесс загрузки остальной части веб-сайта, в результате чего я надеялся, что оранжевую слизь `.goo-two` можно использовать для раскрытия содержимого.

Это становится еще сложнее, потому что оранжевая слизь начинает капать до того, как закончится движение коричневой слизи, что было бы идеальным моментом для изменения фона контейнера `.goo-container` с цвета `skyblue` на `transparent`, хотя полупрозрачный градиент, как фон, может вероятно,  использоваться для достижения этого. (Либо это, либо что-то совсем другое, например, дублируйте оранжевый слой и используйте один, чтобы обрезать коричневый путь, а другой, чтобы вырезать слой skyblue).

```js
const
  gooCont = document.querySelector('div.goo-container'),
  gooOne = gooCont.querySelector('div.goo-one'),
  gooTwo = gooCont.querySelector('div.goo-two'),
  rand = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min

gooCont.style.setProperty('--translateY', `translateY(-${innerWidth * 0.21 / innerHeight * 100 + 100}%)`)
generateGoo(gooOne)

function generateGoo(goo) {
  const
    randQty = rand(20,30),
    unit = innerWidth / (randQty - 1) / innerWidth * 100
  if (getComputedStyle(goo).display === 'none') goo.style.display = 'block'
  for (let i = 0; i < randQty; i++) {
    const
      div = document.createElement('div'),
      minWidthPx = innerWidth < 500 ? innerWidth * 0.1 : innerWidth * 0.05,
      minMaxWidthPx = innerWidth < 500 ? innerWidth * 0.2 : innerWidth * 0.1,
      widthPx = rand(minWidthPx, minMaxWidthPx),
      widthPerc = widthPx / innerWidth * 100,
      heightPx = rand(widthPx / 2, widthPx * 3),
      heightPerc = heightPx / gooCont.getBoundingClientRect().height * 100,
      translateY = rand(45, 70),
      targetTranslateY = rand(15, 100),
      borderRadiusPerc = rand(40, 50)
    div.style.width = widthPerc + '%'
    div.style.height = heightPerc + '%'
    div.style.left = i * unit + '%'
    div.style.transform = `translate(-50%, ${translateY}%)`
    div.style.borderRadius = borderRadiusPerc + '%'
    div.setAttribute('data-translate', targetTranslateY)
    goo.appendChild(div)
  }
  goo.style.transform = `translateY(0)`
  goo.childNodes.forEach(
    v => v.style.transform = `translateY(${v.getAttribute('data-translate')}%)`
  )
}

setTimeout(() => {
  gooTwo.innerHTML = ''
  generateGoo(gooTwo)
}, 2300)
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: red;
}

div.goo-container {
  --translateY: translateY(-165%);
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: skyblue;
}

div.goo-container > div.goo-one,
div.goo-container > div.goo-two {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: var(--translateY);
  filter: url('#goo-filter');
  background: #5b534a;
  transition: transform 2.8s linear;
}

div.goo-container > div.goo-one > div,
div.goo-container > div.goo-two > div {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #5b534a;
  transition: transform 2.8s linear;
}

div.goo-container > div.goo-two {
  display: none;
  transition: transform 2.8s linear;
}

div.goo-container > div.goo-two,
div.goo-container > div.goo-two > div {
  background: orange;
}

svg {
  /* Prevents effect on Firefox */
  /* display: none; */
}
```

```html
<div class='goo-container'>
  <div class='goo-one'></div>
  <div class='goo-two'></div>
</div>
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1'>
  <defs>
    <filter id='goo-filter'>
      <feGaussianBlur in='SourceGraphic' stdDeviation='10' result='blur' />
      <feColorMatrix in='blur' mode='matrix' values='1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 18 -7' result='goo' />
      <feBlend in='SourceGraphic' in2='goo' />
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [“Clipping” Background to See Below Itself in Stacking Context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64976357/7394871) от участника  [@oldboy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7543162/oldboy).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/64976357/7394871

Answer (score 3):

Сначала я начну создавать форму, используя один div и несколько градиентов.

Вот идея использования нечетких градиентов (одинаковой ширины и разной высоты), которые мы можем легко расположить:

```css
:root {
  --c:linear-gradient(red,red);
}
div.goo-container {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:-20px;
  right:-20px;
  height:200px;
  background:
     var(--c) calc(0*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) 80%,
     var(--c) calc(1*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) 60%,
     var(--c) calc(2*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) 30%,
     var(--c) calc(3*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) 50%,
     var(--c) calc(4*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) 59%,
     var(--c) calc(5*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) 48%,
     var(--c) calc(6*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) 36%,
     var(--c) calc(7*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) 70%,
     var(--c) calc(8*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) 75%,
     var(--c) calc(9*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) 35%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  filter: url('#goo-filter');
}
```

```html
<div class='goo-container'>
</div>



<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1'>
  <defs>
    <filter id='goo-filter'>
      <feGaussianBlur in='SourceGraphic' stdDeviation='10' result='blur' />
      <feColorMatrix in='blur' mode='matrix' values='1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 20 -5' result='goo' />
      <feBlend in='SourceGraphic' in2='goo' />
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

У нас также может быть переменная ширина, и здесь JS будет нужен для их генерации:

```css
:root {
  --c:linear-gradient(red,red);
}
div.goo-container {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:-20px;
  right:-20px;
  height:200px;
  background:
     var(--c) 0     0/20px 80%,
     var(--c) 20px  0/80px 60%,
     var(--c) 100px 0/10px 30%,
     var(--c) 110px 0/50px 50%,
     var(--c) 160px 0/30px 59%,
     var(--c) 190px 0/80px 48%,
     var(--c) 270px 0/10px 36%,
     var(--c) 280px 0/20px 70%,
     var(--c) 300px 0/50px 75%,
     var(--c) 350px 0/80px 35%
     /* and so on ... */;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  filter: url('#goo-filter');
}
```

```html
<div class='goo-container'>
</div>
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1'>
  <defs>
    <filter id='goo-filter'>
      <feGaussianBlur in='SourceGraphic' stdDeviation='10' result='blur' />
      <feColorMatrix in='blur' mode='matrix' values='1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 20 -5' result='goo' />
      <feBlend in='SourceGraphic' in2='goo' />
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Затем с дополнительным CSS мы можем получить нашу первую анимацию:

```css
:root {
  --c:linear-gradient(red,red);
}
div.goo-container {
  position:fixed;
  height:100vh;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  background:red;
  transform:translateY(-150vh);
  animation:move 3s 1s forwards;
}

div.goo-container::after {
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  top:100%;
  left:-20px;
  right:-20px;
  height:50vh;
  margin:0 -20px;
  background:
     var(--c) calc(0*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) 80%,
     var(--c) calc(1*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) 60%,
     var(--c) calc(2*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) 30%,
     var(--c) calc(3*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) 50%,
     var(--c) calc(4*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) 59%,
     var(--c) calc(5*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) 48%,
     var(--c) calc(6*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) 36%,
     var(--c) calc(7*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) 70%,
     var(--c) calc(8*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) 75%,
     var(--c) calc(9*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) 35%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  filter: url('#goo-filter');
}
div.goo-container::before {
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  top:100%;
  height:150vh;
  background:blue;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}

@keyframes move {
  to {
     transform:translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='goo-container'>
</div>
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1'>
  <defs>
    <filter id='goo-filter'>
      <feGaussianBlur in='SourceGraphic' stdDeviation='10' result='blur' />
      <feColorMatrix in='blur' mode='matrix' values='1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 20 -5' result='goo' />
      <feBlend in='SourceGraphic' in2='goo' />
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Все еще не идеально, но мы также можем добавить градиентную анимацию, чтобы настроить размеры:

```css
:root {
  --c:linear-gradient(red,red);
}
div.goo-container {
  position:fixed;
  height:100vh;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  background:red;
  transform:translateY(-150vh);
  animation:move 5s 0.5s forwards;
}

div.goo-container::after {
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  top:100%;
  left:-20px;
  right:-20px;
  height:50vh;
  margin:0 -20px;
  background:
     var(--c) calc(0*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) 80%,
     var(--c) calc(1*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) 60%,
     var(--c) calc(2*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) 30%,
     var(--c) calc(3*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) 50%,
     var(--c) calc(4*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) 59%,
     var(--c) calc(5*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) 48%,
     var(--c) calc(6*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) 36%,
     var(--c) calc(7*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) 70%,
     var(--c) calc(8*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) 75%,
     var(--c) calc(9*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) 35%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  filter: url('#goo-filter');
  animation:grad 4.5s 1s forwards;
}
div.goo-container::before {
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  top:100%;
  height:150vh;
  background:blue;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}

@keyframes move {
  to {
     transform:translateY(0);
  }
}
@keyframes grad {
  to {
     background-size:
     calc(100%/10) 50%,
     calc(100%/10) 75%,
     calc(100%/10) 20%,
     calc(100%/10) 60%,
     calc(100%/10) 55%,
     calc(100%/10) 80%,
     calc(100%/10) 23%,
     calc(100%/10) 80%,
     calc(100%/10) 90%,
     calc(100%/10) 20%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='goo-container'>
</div>
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1'>
  <defs>
    <filter id='goo-filter'>
      <feGaussianBlur in='SourceGraphic' stdDeviation='10' result='blur' />
      <feColorMatrix in='blur' mode='matrix' values='1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 20 -5' result='goo' />
      <feBlend in='SourceGraphic' in2='goo' />
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Вышеупомянутое немного сложно, потому что положение каждого градиента будет зависеть от размера всего предыдущего (возможно, здесь потребуется JS или SASS для генерации кода)

---

Для второй анимации мы сделаем то же самое, но мы считаем, что слои градиента внутри свойства маски имеют противоположный эффект (слои градиента будут удалены, чтобы увидеть оставшуюся часть)

```css
:root {
  --c:linear-gradient(red,red);
  background:pink;
}
div.goo-container {
  position:fixed;
  height:150vh;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  transform:translateY(-200vh);
  animation:move 8s 0.5s forwards;
  filter: url('#goo-filter');
}
div.goo-container > div {
  height:100%;
  background:red;
  -webkit-mask:
     var(--c) calc(0*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10 + 4px) 40vh,
     var(--c) calc(1*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10 + 4px) 30vh,
     var(--c) calc(2*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10 + 4px) 15vh,
     var(--c) calc(3*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10 + 4px) 20vh,
     var(--c) calc(4*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10 + 4px) 29vh,
     var(--c) calc(5*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10 + 4px) 35vh,
     var(--c) calc(6*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10 + 4px) 12vh,
     var(--c) calc(7*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10 + 4px) 50vh,
     var(--c) calc(8*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10 + 4px) 48vh,
     var(--c) calc(9*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10 + 4px) 40vh,
     linear-gradient(#fff,#fff);
  -webkit-mask-composite:destination-out;
  mask-composite:exclude;
  -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
  animation:mask 7.5s 1s forwards;
}

div.goo-container::after {
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  top:100%;
  left:-20px;
  right:-20px;
  height:50vh;
  margin:0 -20px;
  background:
     var(--c) calc(0*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) 80%,
     var(--c) calc(1*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) 60%,
     var(--c) calc(2*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) 30%,
     var(--c) calc(3*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) 50%,
     var(--c) calc(4*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) 59%,
     var(--c) calc(5*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) 48%,
     var(--c) calc(6*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) 36%,
     var(--c) calc(7*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) 60%,
     var(--c) calc(8*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) 65%,
     var(--c) calc(9*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) 35%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  filter: url('#goo-filter');
  animation:grad 7.5s 1s forwards;
}
div.goo-container::before {
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  top:100%;
  height:150vh;
  background:blue;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}

@keyframes move {
  to {
     transform:translateY(150vh);
  }
}
@keyframes grad {
  to {
     background-size:
     calc(100%/10) 50%,
     calc(100%/10) 75%,
     calc(100%/10) 20%,
     calc(100%/10) 60%,
     calc(100%/10) 55%,
     calc(100%/10) 80%,
     calc(100%/10) 23%,
     calc(100%/10) 80%,
     calc(100%/10) 90%,
     calc(100%/10) 20%;
  }
}
@keyframes mask {
  to {
     -webkit-mask-size:
     calc(100%/10) 30vh,
     calc(100%/10) 10vh,
     calc(100%/10) 50vh,
     calc(100%/10) 45vh,
     calc(100%/10) 12vh,
     calc(100%/10) 22vh,
     calc(100%/10) 60vh,
     calc(100%/10) 10vh,
     calc(100%/10) 8vh,
     calc(100%/10) 35vh,
     auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu sodales lectus. Sed non erat accumsan, placerat purus quis, sodales mi. Suspendisse potenti. Sed eu viverra odio. </p>

<div class='goo-container'>
  <div></div>
</div>
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1'>
  <defs>
    <filter id='goo-filter'>
      <feGaussianBlur in='SourceGraphic' stdDeviation='10' result='blur' />
      <feColorMatrix in='blur' mode='matrix' values='1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 20 -5' result='goo' />
      <feBlend in='SourceGraphic' in2='goo' />
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Мы делаем некоторую оптимизацию кода и оставляем только один элемент:

```css
:root {
  --c:linear-gradient(red,red);
  background:pink;
}
div.goo-container {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  transform:translateY(-150%);
  animation:move 8s 0.5s forwards;
  filter: url('#goo-filter');
}

div.goo-container::after {
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  top:-50%;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:-50%;
  background:
     var(--c) calc(0*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 40vh),
     var(--c) calc(1*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 30vh),
     var(--c) calc(2*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 35vh),
     var(--c) calc(3*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 50vh),
     var(--c) calc(4*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 10vh),
     var(--c) calc(5*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 15vh),
     var(--c) calc(6*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 30vh),
     var(--c) calc(7*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 28vh),
     var(--c) calc(8*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 30vh),
     var(--c) calc(9*100%/9) 0/calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 50vh);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask:
     var(--c) calc(0*100%/9) 100%/calc(100%/10 + 4px) calc(100% - 20vh),
     var(--c) calc(1*100%/9) 100%/calc(100%/10 + 4px) calc(100% - 10vh),
     var(--c) calc(2*100%/9) 100%/calc(100%/10 + 4px) calc(100% - 50vh),
     var(--c) calc(3*100%/9) 100%/calc(100%/10 + 4px) calc(100% - 30vh),
     var(--c) calc(4*100%/9) 100%/calc(100%/10 + 4px) calc(100% - 35vh),
     var(--c) calc(5*100%/9) 100%/calc(100%/10 + 4px) calc(100% - 10vh),
     var(--c) calc(6*100%/9) 100%/calc(100%/10 + 4px) calc(100% - 50vh),
     var(--c) calc(7*100%/9) 100%/calc(100%/10 + 4px) calc(100% - 40vh),
     var(--c) calc(8*100%/9) 100%/calc(100%/10 + 4px) calc(100% - 45vh),
     var(--c) calc(9*100%/9) 100%/calc(100%/10 + 4px) calc(100% - 35vh);
  -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
  filter: inherit;
  animation: inherit;
  animation-name:grad, mask;
}
div.goo-container::before {
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  top:50%;
  bottom:-150%;
  background:blue;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}

@keyframes move {
  to {
     transform:translateY(200%);
  }
}
@keyframes grad {
  to {
     background-size:
     calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 10vh),
     calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 50vh),
     calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 30vh),
     calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 10vh),
     calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 40vh),
     calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 25vh),
     calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 32vh),
     calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 18vh),
     calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 50vh),
     calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 10vh);
  }
}
@keyframes mask {
  to {
     -webkit-mask-size:
     calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 10vh),
     calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 50vh),
     calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 10vh),
     calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 30vh),
     calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 32vh),
     calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 40vh),
     calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 50vh),
     calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 25vh),
     calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 18vh),
     calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 10vh);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu sodales lectus. Sed non erat accumsan, placerat purus quis, sodales mi. Suspendisse potenti. Sed eu viverra odio. </p>

<div class='goo-container'></div>
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1'>
  <defs>
    <filter id='goo-filter'>
      <feGaussianBlur in='SourceGraphic' stdDeviation='10' result='blur' />
      <feColorMatrix in='blur' mode='matrix' values='1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 20 -5' result='goo' />
      <feBlend in='SourceGraphic' in2='goo' />
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

И, наконец, динамическое решение с использованием SASS для создания слоев градиента и маски:

https://codepen.io/t_afif/pen/oNzxYgV

**UPDATE**

Еще одна идея без использования маски. Хитрость заключается в том, чтобы центрировать градиенты. Это решение будет иметь большую поддержку, но форма как снизу, так и сверху будет симметричной.

```css
:root {
  --c:linear-gradient(red,red);
  background:pink;
}
div.goo-container {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  transform:translateY(-150%);
  animation:move 8s 0.5s forwards;
  filter: url('#goo-filter');
}

div.goo-container::after {
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  top:-50%;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:-50%;
  background:
     var(--c) calc(0*100%/9) 50%/calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 80vh),
     var(--c) calc(1*100%/9) 50%/calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 60vh),
     var(--c) calc(2*100%/9) 50%/calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 70vh),
     var(--c) calc(3*100%/9) 50%/calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 100vh),
     var(--c) calc(4*100%/9) 50%/calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 20vh),
     var(--c) calc(5*100%/9) 50%/calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 30vh),
     var(--c) calc(6*100%/9) 50%/calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 60vh),
     var(--c) calc(7*100%/9) 50%/calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 56vh),
     var(--c) calc(8*100%/9) 50%/calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 60vh),
     var(--c) calc(9*100%/9) 50%/calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 100vh);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  filter: inherit;
  animation:grad 8s 0.5s forwards;
}
div.goo-container::before {
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  top:50%;
  bottom:-150%;
  background:blue;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}

@keyframes move {
  to {
     transform:translateY(200%);
  }
}
@keyframes grad {
  to {
     background-size:
     calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 20vh),
     calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 100vh),
     calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 60vh),
     calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 20vh),
     calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 80vh),
     calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 50vh),
     calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 64vh),
     calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 34vh),
     calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 100vh),
     calc(100%/10) calc(100% - 20vh);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu sodales lectus. Sed non erat accumsan, placerat purus quis, sodales mi. Suspendisse potenti. Sed eu viverra odio. </p>



<div class='goo-container'></div>
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1'>
  <defs>
    <filter id='goo-filter'>
      <feGaussianBlur in='SourceGraphic' stdDeviation='10' result='blur' />
      <feColorMatrix in='blur' mode='matrix' values='1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 20 -5' result='goo' />
      <feBlend in='SourceGraphic' in2='goo' />
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

И версия SASS:    https://codepen.io/t_afif/pen/wvzGoeJ

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65152419/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Это попытка избежать всех сложностей с фильтром, маскированием и компоновкой. Это просто SMIL-анимация некоторых путей Безье, которая должна поддерживаться без каких-либо ошибок. Я пока не нашел решения, при котором на экране одновременно появляются первая и вторая волна.

Я признаю, что самой трудоемкой частью была разработка алгоритма пути, все остальное относительно просто.

"Слизь" (`goo`) - это область с верхней и нижней границами, которая перемещается по клиентской области, при этом форма пути изменяется. Я попытался описать в комментариях к коду, какие части можно изменить. Базовая структура композиции контура обеспечивает важное ограничение: контур в целом не должен иметь различающуюся последовательность команд контура для разных ключевых кадров анимации, иначе плавная анимация не удастся. Смена номеров не должна быть проблемой.

Позади слизи находится непрозрачный прямоугольник, который изначально скрывает содержимое. Он скрывается в тот момент, пока слизь бегает по экрану.

Время анимации определяется атрибутами элементов `<set>` и `<animate>`. Обратите внимание, что анимация слизи длится 6 секунд, а скрытие фонового прямоугольника происходит через 3 секунды. Это распределение соответствует значениям атрибута `<animate keyTimes>: 0; 0,5; 1`, которые можно прочитать как `0%, 50%, 100%`, как время для ключевых кадров. Время срабатывания триггера `<set>` должно совпадать с этим средним ключевым кадром, так как это время, когда слизь покрывает всю клиентскую область.

```js
const
  rand = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min,
  flatten = (x, y) => `${x.toFixed(2)},${y.toFixed(2)}`

function randomPoints(width, height) {
  const
    from = [],
    to = []

  let x = 0, old_extent = 0
  while (x + old_extent < width) {
    //ширина единственного липкого языка слизи
    const extent = rand(5, 20)
    // rand () часть: расстояние между языками
    x += (from.length ? 1.5 : 0) * (old_extent + extent) + rand(0, 5)
    const data = {
        x1: x - extent,
        x2: x + extent,
        // «округлость»: насколько далеко будет нижняя точка языка
        // растягиваться ниже своей определяющей черты (качественная значение)
        dty: extent * rand(0.4, 1.4)
      }

    // y: положение языка над границей экрана в начале
    // Обратите внимание, что -20 дает возможность «округлости» не пересекать порог.
    from.push({ ...data, y: rand(-50, -20) })
    // y: положение языка под границей экрана в конце
    // Обратите внимание, что цифра 10 дает возможность «округлости» не переходить порог.
    to.push({ ...data, y: rand(10, 105) + height })

    old_extent = extent
  }

  return { from, to }
}

function generatePath(points, path, back) {
  const qti = points.length
  let old_dtx, old_dty

  if (back) points.reverse()

  for (let i = 0; i < qti; i++) {
    const
      x1 = back ? points[i].x2 : points[i].x1,
      x2 = back ? points[i].x1 : points[i].x2,
      dtx = (x2 - x1) / 2
    let dty = 0

    if (i == 0) {
      path.push(
        back ? 'L' : 'M', 
        flatten(x1, points[i].y), 
        'Q',
        flatten(x1 + dtx, points[i].y),        
        flatten(x2, points[i].y)
      );
    } else {
      if (i !== qti - 1) {
        const
          y0 = points[i - 1].y,
          y1 = points[i].y,
          y2 = points[i + 1].y,
          // числа дают значение "округлости" для разных случаев:
          // язык, простирающийся ниже своих соседей = 1 (закругление вниз)
          // язычок, отставший от своих соседей = -0,1 (округление вверх)
          // другие случаи = 0.5
          down = y1 > y0 ? y1 > y2 ? 1 : 0.5 : y1 > y2 ? 0.5 : -0.1
        dty = points[i].dty * down //min absichern
      }

      path.push(
        'C', 
        flatten(points[i - 1][back ? 'x1' : 'x2'] + old_dtx / 2, points[i - 1].y - old_dty / 2),
        flatten(x1 - dtx / 2, points[i].y - dty / 2),
        flatten(x1, points[i].y), 
        'Q',
        flatten(x1 + dtx, points[i].y + dty),
        flatten(x2, points[i].y)
      );
    }
    old_dtx = dtx, old_dty = dty
  }

  if (back) { 
    points.reverse()
    path.push('Z')
  }
}

function generateArea(width, height) {
  const
    // языковые контрольные точки для первой волны
    firstPoints = randomPoints(width, height),
    // языковые контрольные точки для второй волны
    secondPoints = randomPoints(width, height),
    start = [],
    mid = [],
    end = []

  // first keyframe
  generatePath(firstPoints.from, start, false)
  generatePath(secondPoints.from, start, true)

  // second keyframe
  generatePath(firstPoints.to, mid, false)
  generatePath(secondPoints.from, mid, true)

  // third keyframe
  generatePath(firstPoints.to, end, false)
  generatePath(secondPoints.to, end, true)
  
  return [
    start.join(' '), 
    mid.join(' '), 
    end.join(' ')
  ]
}

const rect = document.querySelector('svg').getBoundingClientRect()
const animate = document.querySelector('#gooAnimate')
const areas = generateArea(rect.width, rect.height)

animate.setAttribute('values', areas.join(';'))
animate.beginElement() // trigger animation start
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}
#content {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #faa;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 1em;
}
svg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
#veil {
  fill: skyblue;
}
#goo {
  fill: #5b534a;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="">consectetur</a> adipiscing elit. Nam eu sodales lectus. Sed non erat accumsan, placerat purus quis, sodales mi. Suspendisse potenti. Sed eu viverra odio. </p>

</div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect id="veil" width="100%" height="100%">
    <!-- background animation start time is relative to goo animation start time -->
    <set attributeName="display" to="none" begin="gooAnimate.begin+3s" fill="freeze" />
  </rect>
  <path id="goo" d="" >
    <animate id="gooAnimate" attributeName="d"
             begin="indefinite" dur="6s" fill="freeze" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" />
  </path>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65162632/7394871) от участника  [@ccprog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4996779/ccprog).</sub>